# How do I get rid of thousands of lines

Tags: javascript, html

To show which course a student is taking, I wrote these simple lines, click the student and see the course, but there seems to be thousands of code lines since I should list so many students and courses. Is there a way to write a single function to get the value of the object instead of writing a seperate function for each click?

```js
//and goes on thousands of times like this...
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");  
var students = {
   student1: "english",
   student2: "maths",
   student3: "history",
   student4: "geography",
   student5: "science",
   student6: "maths",
   student7: "maths",
   student8: "history",
   student9: "french",
   student10: "geography",
};
//and there are thousands of students...

function f1(){txt.innerHTML = students.student1;};
function f2(){txt.innerHTML = students.student2;};
function f3(){txt.innerHTML = students.student3;};
function f4(){txt.innerHTML = students.student4;};
function f5(){txt.innerHTML = students.student5;};
function f6(){txt.innerHTML = students.student6;};
function f7(){txt.innerHTML = students.student7;};
function f8(){txt.innerHTML = students.student8;};
function f9(){txt.innerHTML = students.student9;};
function f10(){txt.innerHTML = students.student10;};
// so there are thousands of functions...
```

```html
 <a class="k"  onClick="f1(); return false;" href="#">student1</a><br/>
 <a class="k"  onClick="f2(); return false;" href="#">student2</a><br/>
 <a class="k"  onClick="f3(); return false;" href="#">student3</a><br/>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Actually I tried this, reasoning that it would work:

```
var stdnt = document.querySelectorAll(".k);
var x = stdnt.innerHTML;
var result = "";

if ( x === students[x] ){
    x = students[x];
}
result = x;
function forAll (){
    txt.innerHTML = result;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all (I guess it's natural for an absolute beginner). I badly need an idea.

Comment: You forgot to add a second parenthesis `"` to the querySelector.

Comment: Yes, typo! but it doesn't work again . The only thing I get is "undefined" error.

Comment: Also, you put javascript comments in the HTML.

Comment: Do you really want each student to see the curriculum of all students? Do you really want to update your document each semester? It would seem to me that your document is not the single source of truth and, if you have the possibility, should instead try to retrieve this information from the database that already keeps track of this.

Comment: Each student can see the course information, and I hope I will find a way to update the courses automatically(providing I improve my javascript skills).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could condense it to use a single function and hand over `innerHTML` of the anchor elemenet. This string can be used as accessor for the object.

```js
var txt = document.getElementById("txt");  
var students = {
   student1: "english",
   student2: "maths",
   student3: "history",
   student4: "geography",
   student5: "science",
   student6: "maths",
   student7: "maths",
   student8: "history",
   student9: "french",
   student10: "geography",
};

function f(key) {
    txt.innerHTML = students[key];
};
```

```html
<a class="k" onClick="f(this.innerHTML); return false;" href="#">student1</a><br/>
<a class="k" onClick="f(this.innerHTML); return false;" href="#">student2</a><br/>
<a class="k" onClick="f(this.innerHTML); return false;" href="#">student3</a><br/>
<div id="txt"></div>
```

Comment: @Hakangöçmen - simplest does not necessarily mean best. Nina is normally not one who posts simple code, but here, you will have to update the HTML when you get a new student. in mine only one update needed to the lookup table

Comment: @mplungjan - I agree, probably you have shown one of the most efficient methods for the project, but the thing is I started to learn javascript only a few weeks ago and I think I need some more time and practice to go further. But I wrote down all the offers made here, and they will definitely guide me in future. Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this

It is using several recommended methods

1. eventListeners
2. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
3. delegation

```js
const students = {
  student1: "english",
  student2: "maths",
  student3: "history",
  student4: "geography",
  student5: "science",
  student6: "maths",
  student7: "maths",
  student8: "history",
  student9: "french",
  student10: "geography",
};
// create the html so only one place to add a student
const html = Object.entries(students)
  .map(entry => `<a href="#" class="k" 
    data-student="${entry[1]}">${entry[0]}</a>`);

// on page load fill the student Div     
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const div = document.getElementById("studentDiv");
  const text = document.getElementById('text')
  div.innerHTML = html.join('<br/>');
  // delegate the click to the container, so only ONE event handler is used
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains('k')) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from executing
      text.innerHTML = tgt.dataset.student;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="studentDiv"></div>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Simpler

```js
const students = {
  student1: "english",
  student2: "maths",
  student3: "history",
  student4: "geography",
  student5: "science",
  student6: "maths",
  student7: "maths",
  student8: "history",
  student9: "french",
  student10: "geography",
};
// create the html so only one place to add a student
const html = Object.entries(students)
  .map(entry => `<a href="#" class="k">${entry[0]}</a>`);

// on page load fill the student Div     
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  const div = document.getElementById("studentDiv");
  const text = document.getElementById('text')
  div.innerHTML = html.join('<br/>');
  // delegate the click to the container, so only ONE event handler is used
  div.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const tgt = e.target;
    if (tgt.classList.contains('k')) {
      e.preventDefault(); // stop the link from executing
      text.innerHTML = students[tgt.textContent]
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="studentDiv"></div>
<div id="text"></div>
```

Comment: why do you use `dataset`, if the target is always known?

Comment: That is a good one. Added a simpler one that uses the lookup like you did

Answer (score 1):

You can make this in one function and maintaining the html for example, one to handle the id of the course:

```
<a class="k"  onClick="getCourse(“student1”); return false;" href="#">student1</a><br/>


function getCourse(student) { // Contains the student
   txt.innerHTML = students[student];
 }
```

Comment: Inline event handlers are not recommended. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65279086/295783) for a better answer